# Convergence and evaluation of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\ln {(2n+1)n \over (n+1)(2n-1)}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, closed-form

I am trying to evaluate

> $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\ln{(2n+1)n \over (n+1)(2n-1)}$$

First, we notice
$${(2n+1)n \over (n+1)(2n-1)} = {2n^2+n -1 + 1 \over 2n^2+n-1} = 1 +  {1 \over 2n^2+n-1}= 1 + {1 \over (n+1)(2n-1)}$$
Then, we use ${x \over 1+x} \le \ln(1+x) \le x$:
$${1 \over (2n+1)n} \le \ln\left(1 + {1 \over (n+1)(2n-1)} \right) \le {1 \over (n+1)(2n-1)}$$
Now, I am going for the squeeze theorem with the partial sum
$${1 \over 3} + {1 \over 10} + \dots + {1 \over (2p+1)p} \le \ln\left( 1 + {1 \over 2} \right) + \ln\left( 1 + {1 \over 9} \right) + \dots +\ln\left( 1 + {1 \over (p+1)(2p-1)} \right) \\ \le {1 \over 2} + {1 \over 9} + \dots + {1 \over (p+1)(2p-1)}$$
I get stuck on reorganizing the terms.

Comment: The squeeze lemma won't work here to find a value, but you can show, by giving an upper, that the series converges.

Comment: This is two telescoping sums. The terms will cancel.

Comment: Great catch @DavidQuinn

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**. This may be seen a limit of two *telescoping sums*:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^N\ln{(2n+1)n \over (n+1)(2n-1)}=\sum_{n=1}^N\left(\ln(2n+1)-\ln(2n-1)\right)-\sum_{n=1}^N\left(\ln(n+1)-\ln(n)\right).
$$