# Evaluate $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \ln\left( \frac{n(2n+1)}{(n+1)(2n-1)}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, telescopic-series

> Evaluate $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \ln\left( \frac{n(2n+1)}{(n+1)(2n-1)}\right)$

---

**My Approach**

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \ln\left( \frac{n(2n+1)}{(n+1)(2n-1)}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty ln(\left(n)(2n+1)\right) - ln(\left(n+1)(2n-1)\right) \\=\sum_{n=1}^\infty ln(n) + ln(2n+1) -ln(n+1)-ln(2n-1) $$

now we can re-write as
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty ln(n) -ln(n+1) \ + \sum_{n=1}^\infty ln(2n+1) - ln(2n-1)$$

Doing the partials sums we can find and take the limit of $S_n$ to find the value of the Series.

$$S_n = ln(1) + ln(1) -ln(n+1) +ln(2n+1) \\ \lim_{n \to \infty} S_n = \lim_{n \to \infty}ln\left(\frac{2n+1}{n+1}\right)= ln(2) $$

I want to know if what I did is legit because the answer is correct (according to the book)

Comment: Where did $\ln(2n+1)$ go? I think for the third line you meant to rewrite the expression as $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\ln(n) - \ln(n+1) \right) + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\ln(2+1) - \ln(2n-1)\right)$ ?

Comment: A coefficient of 2 got dropped somewhere throwing things off.  Also, there's definitely some brackets missing in there in the first line.  It should be the natural log of a product, not the product of a natural log and a polynomial.

Comment: Yes, sorry guys I will edit those things

Comment: $s_n$ should of have $log(2n+1)$ not $log(2n-1)$. Otherwise, looks good.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convergence and evaluation of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\ln {(2n+1)n \over (n+1)(2n-1)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2034917/convergence-and-evaluation-of-sum-n-1-infty-ln-2n1n-over-n12n-1) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bn%3D1%7D%5E%5Cinfty%20%5Cln%5Cleft(%20%5Cfrac%7Bn(2n%2B1)%7D%7B(n%2B1)(2n-1)%7D%5Cright)%24&p=2). As the [answer](/a/4680536) below indicates, you need to be careful with handling infinite sums. Also, as the duplicate question [answer](/a/2034923) states, you're using ...

Comment: (cont.) two [telescoping series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series), so you may wish to explicitly mention this in your proof. Last, but not least, welcome to Math SE.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who "wasted" a little time to help me, I'm still confused about whether I can divide into two sums because they are divergent, and thanks for the reception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \ln(n) -\ln(n+1) \ + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \ln(2n+1) - \ln(2n-1)$$

Here you cannot split them into two summations, because both of them are divergent. Instead, you have to keep them into one summation,

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\ln(n) -\ln(n+1) \right)+ (\ln(2n+1) - \ln(2n-1))$$

Next, do the parital sum as you did for $S_n$, then take the limit. Your result is correct.

Comment: I'm still a little confused on whether or not I can split into two sums, as said in the comment above the other post has been resolved as I did

Comment: You can split them ONLY IF both of them are convergent, otherwise you can't, because it is indetermined for $\infty-\infty$

Comment: Ahh got it, I will do as you said then, thanks